# SharePoint 2010 Release Candidate

Tags: 2010

Does anyone know of a release date for the Release Candidate of SharePoint 2010?  I know the launch is scheduled for June 2010, so I am guessing an RC would be out in February/March 2010, but I have seen nothing to confirm this.  Also, is there any new on if this release will include the updates to the Security model and the use of SAML based tokens?

Comment: The launch date for SharePoint 2010 is May 12th.  RTM is expected in April.  More information can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2010/03/05/sharepoint-2010-office-2010-launch.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RC has also now been released to Technical Beta participants. This is a wider group than TAP but still not public.

It is only for evaluation and under NDA (including bugs and workarounds). The NDA does not apply to information publically released by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

The Release Candidate was made available to members of the Office 2010 Technology Adaption Program (TAP) on 19th Jan. All subject to strict NDA

Comment: Thanks Rick!  This is good news that it is in the hands of the TAP members.  Makes me hopeful that we might also see this release, although Greg's comment below has merit too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything communicated yet.  I think there is still quite a bit to clean up in Beta 2 so I wouldn't be surprised to see it come out as late as April or May.

Answer (score 0):

Tweets from SharePoint Connections in Amsterdam this week told that the RC already is done, can anyone confirm?
/WW

Comment: Even if this could be confirmed, it couldn't be confirmed due to NDA. Make sense? ;-)

Comment: Haha, yeah. Was just throwing out a thin rope. I hope for some kind of beta refresh and don't expect RC just yet...

Answer (score 0):

Public availability for a Release Candidate has not been annouced yet. I think you are right about your timing, though. If a Release Candidate or a second Beta isn't made available soon, one might start to question the June Final Release date. As to speculation on updates including in the next test version, it's fair to say they should be widespread, but details like SAML will be kept tight until public release.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind also that an RC1 (or 0) may not be made available to the public or even MSDN, even if such a build exists - all depends on the quality of the build & how Microsoft is feeling that day.

Answer (score 0):

The RC is available